# how to make href while using htaccess rewrite for dynamic url

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, href

I want to use .htaccess file to make friendly URLs. But when I click on the link which is specified in href

```
<a href="category.php?id= <?php echo "{$row['name']}"; ?>">Example </a>
```

`$row['name']` is dynamic. data is present in MySQL database.

Code (category.php):

```
<?php
if($_GET['id']){
  $result = $_GET['id'];
}
echo "this is {$result} page";
?>
```

This just store the passed parameter in `$result` variable and displays it on screen.

Code (.HTACCESS file):

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   ^website/(.+)$   category.php?id=$1
```

when I click on the link it shows the URL like `http://mydomain.com/category.php?id=Rohit`
instead of `http://mydomain.com/website/rohit`.

However when I write URL manually to `http://mydomain.com/website/rohit` it shows the same page. Which indicates that .htaccess file is working. I want to show the above URL directly when I click word Example.

One example
When we click on page barack obama in Wikipedia it goes to `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barack_obama` but the original link works too -`http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Barack_obama`. Both pages show the same data.
They don't show the second URL to the user but the other one. I want to achieve same kind of result.

How to write the link such that it will goes to rewrite URL?

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
<a href="category.php?id= <?php echo "{$row['name']}"; ?>">Example </a>
```

to

```
<a href="website/<?php echo "{$row['name']}"; ?>">Example </a>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do this with apache mode_rewrite and mod_replace, but I would not recommend it. Since I guess you would like to support it in both ways and you are using PHP I would create a function (or class/method) to rewrite your written urls.
i.e.:

```
<a href="<?php getUrl('category.php', $row['name']}) ?>">Example</a>
```

This way it is possible to handle different URL's based on the user request.

```
function getUrl($phpfile, $argument) {

   if ('<some logic to check if user request is rewritten') {    
      return "website/" . $argument; 
   } else {    
      return $phpfile . "?id=" . $argument; 
   }
}
```

Comment: This method is more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the url re-writes then in href you have to pass SEO friendly urls by your own; for the best practices create a common function and pass your parameters into that function and generate SEO friendly url for href;

or instead of creating url like category.php?id=123 in href hardcode href url like website/123

or you have to define rules like if user access your page like category.php?id=123 then redirect user to the website/123